# react-router-dom rendering new page over current page

Tags: reactjs, typescript, web, react-router-dom

router-dom`

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
    BrowserRouter as Router,
    Switch,
    Route,
    Link
  } from "react-router-dom";
import Squall from '../pages/squall/Squall';

interface UserProps {
    name: string
    avatar: string
}

class User extends Component<UserProps> {

    constructor(props: UserProps) {
        super(props);
      }

    render() {
        return (
            <Router>
                <Link to="/">
                    Home
                </Link>
                <Link to="/squall">
                    <img src={this.props.avatar} alt={this.props.name}/>
                </Link>

                <Switch>
                    <Route path="/squall">
                        <Squall/>
                    </Route>
                    <Route path="/">
                        
                    </Route>
                </Switch>
            </Router>
        )
    }
}

export default User;
```

why when I click on the element with `<Link to="/squall">`, it renders the `Squall` page over the current page rather than a new one. The "current page" is just `<App/>`. I looked online and the solution was to use the `exact` keyword but still no luck.

Comment: Is `<Route path="/">` rending `App` component? What is the "current page" in this scenario? Does the URL at least update to your `"/squall"` path?

Comment: No, it's just there to make the switch exhaustive. If I try to render `<App/>` there, the website does not load at all. Chrome offers to kill the unresponsive site.

Comment: So `App` is being rendered *outside* the `Router`? This is probably why both are rendered when on the `<Route path="/squall">` path. Can you provide a more [Minimal, Complete, and Reproducible](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) code example? What is rendering `User` component, where is `App` rendered?

Comment: Ok I will, I'm headed off to work but I'll do so when I get back. I'll ping you then if you don't mind taking another look. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should add exact to the path with  "/" due to this that every path include "/" so it's print with it

```
 <Route exact path="/">
       <Component>                   
 </Route>
```